# Truncated Leading Zeros when UDF used

Tags: vba, split, truncate, truncated, leading-zero

I am trying to split text from numbers within an ID (i.e. TEXT008758, TEXT65647095, TEXT065, TEXT0000000047398473, etc..) that varies in length- there is no rhyme or reason. I have written the below UDF code to extract the numbers from the text which works perfectly.

Problem: The leading zero's continue to be truncated from the ID when I perform the UDF. I need the leading zeors as they are a part of the ID convention. I am not sure if a Sub process would be more efficient to convert it to text format and preserve the leading zero's or what. Obtaining a .csv or .txt is not an option so I am wondering what alternatives you fellow wizards can provide. I am a user of python so diving into the VBA world for work has been a learning process.. *sigh*

```
Option Explicit
Public Function NumSplit(ByVal x As String, LeaveNums As Boolean) As Variant
Dim y As String, z As String, n As Long
    For n = 1 To Len(x)
        y = Mid(x, n, 1)
        If LeaveNums = False Then
            If y Like "[A-Za-z ]" Then z = z & y
        Else
            If y Like "[0-9 ]" Then z = z & y
        End If
    Next n
NumSplit = Trim(z)

End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No-repro. The zeroes are preserved. If you use the function in a cell, then Excel converts the result to a number and removes the zeroes, so format the cell as Text before executing the function.

Comment: I can leave my cell as general and the `0`s are left the result returned is a string.  How are you calling it?

Comment: @GSerg I have tried this, if I format to text before I execute the function.. it stays as "NUMBERVALUE(numsplit(AH1238,TRUE))"  text.

Comment: @ScottCraner see above^ -- calling it trough a formula

Comment: Remove the `NUMBERVALUE` it will need to left as a string if you want the leading `0`s

Comment: @ScottCraner ILY ---- As you can see I have been staring at data for too long ... hehe

Comment: SOLVED BY @ScottCraner above if anyone else runs into the issue.